# CMSIS- NN quantization problem for non image input

Tags: python, arm, conv-neural-network, microcontroller, cmsis

I am implemneting a NN for EMG based hand gesture recognition using CMSIS-NN on a microcontroller

My input data, for example is: [0.061035156,0.095214844,0.086669922,0,0.002441406,0.002441406,0,0,0.002441406,0.013427734,0.032958984]

I am using the nn_quantizer.py file provided by ARM on Github (cifar10 example) for quantization to 8 bits. For my dataset it requires the Q2.5 format.

But my predictions on the micro conroller are really bad. The Caffemodel which is used for training has good predictions though.

I am already pre processing the input before putting it on the microcontroller. So I don't need the mean_subtract function generated by cod_gen.py file. So I just convert my preprocessed input vector to 8 bit fixed point and feed to the NN on the controller for inferencing.

What is the possible problem with it?

Can someone plase suggest some solutions

thank you

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to different problems. Without the code for your model, I cannot specify which one.

One option: it could be that you are not quantizing correctly or obtaining the correct Q.Q formats and related shifts. You should quantize all layers, including input, in an incremental procedure. That means, you quantize input, then with its Q.Q format, you can quantize the first layer and so on.

Another option: you should make sure that the weight conversion is carried in the appropriate form. For example, from PyTorch to CMSIS you have to transpose convolution weights (0,2,3,1). Regarding fully connected layers you should reorder them accordingly. A good tutorial is: https://developer.arm.com/solutions/machine-learning-on-arm/developer-material/how-to-guides/converting-a-neural-network-for-arm-cortex-m-with-cmsis-nn/single-page

If you post more details about the problem, like the model and the Q.Q formats of layers, I might be able to help you.

A good example of transforming a model from Keras to CMSIS is: https://github.com/autoas/CMSIS_5/blob/develop/CMSIS/NN/Examples/ARM/arm_nn_examples/mnist/mnist-on-keras.ipynb